# Downloading Host Installer Chrome Remote Desktop 16.04 Chromium

Tags: chromium, remote-desktop

I have installed the Chrome Remote Desktop app from the web store, and I am working on downloading and installing the host installer. When I click the accept and install button on the "Download Chrome Remote Desktop Host Installer, it takes me to a new tab that has the url of

https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/chrome-remote-desktop_current_i386.deb

which just contains an Error 404 Page Not Found.

What does this mean?

Does it mean that my processor, software, browser does not support the host installer?

Comment: Chrome no longer provides 32bit versions. If you're using a 32bit Chrome that version must be very old and shouldn't be used.

Comment: Good to know. I am on an old Dell Latitude D810, which has a 32 bit processor.

Comment: You can still install and use Chromium but not the service you want because it depends on Google directly and they ended support for 32bit in Linux.

Comment: So I've decided to switch to  Linux Mint KDE Plasma 64-bit. Thank you.